How is "plugin-info.html" generated for maven plugins
Below is an excerpt from site.xml for maven-dependency-plugin
    <menu name="Overview">
      <item name="Introduction" href="index.html"/>
      <item name="Goals" href="plugin-info.html"/>
      <item name="Usage" href="usage.html"/>
      <item name="FAQ" href="faq.html"/>
      <!-- According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-152 -->
      <item name="License" href="https://www.apache.org/licenses/"/>
      <item name="Download" href="download.html"/>
    </menu>

Here we can see that Goals is linked to plugin-info.html.
However when I run mvn clean install and mvn site the file plugin-info.html is never generated for me, is there any configuration that I am missing ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765750/plugin-info-html-file-not-being-generated-when-running-maven-site explains it
